# handle authentication exception with symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'd like simply return an apropriate message like `return new Response('authentication faild');` to my client throught an API but it doesn't behave as it suppose to be as in the following code

```
try{
        $token = $this->get('security.authentication.manager')
                      ->authenticate(new UsernamePasswordToken($username, $password, 'main'));
        $this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
    }
    catch (BadCredentialsException $e){
        return new Response('authentication faild', 403);
    }
```

The error returned is the html/css ... code of the login form

Comment: it return the full html/css.... code that suppose de display the login form

Comment: Have a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/xanf/1015146

Comment: I've implemented a solution to a similar problem using an Exception listener. You basically set up a listener to catch all exceptions, then using `if $exception instanceof ...` you can identify which. I then use a redirect to my login page.

Comment: I've register the listener to listen on onCoreException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event) as describes here [link]https://gist.github.com/xanf/1015146[/link] and I guess that the listenert will be called if bad credential but still the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this:

```
<?php

namespace YourBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;

class CatchErrorsEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return ["kernel.exception" => ['catchException', 200]];
    }

    /**
     * @param GetResponseForExceptionEvent $evt
     */
    public function catchException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $evt)
    {
        $request = $evt->getRequest()->getRequestFormat('json');

        if($request != 'json') {
            return;
        }

        $response = $evt->getResponse() ?: new Response();
        $evt->stopPropagation();  // stop the other listener to redirect to login
        $evt->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

This listener will catch the exception and you can send a response your desired way. In this example only if the request is a json request.

Don't forget to register the subscriber as a service:

```
    <service class="YourBundle\EventListener\CatchErrorsEventSubscriber" id="your_bundle.catch_error_event_subscriber">
        <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
    </service>
```